# Installing an older version of angular

Tags: angular

So, I have Angular 6 installed on my computer, but I'm working with legacy code that used Angular 4. Do I need to install Angular 4, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been many changes from Angular v4 to v6. I am assuming when you say "I have Angular 6 installed on my computer" you mean you Globally installed Angular v6.

In that case, to run your project all you will need to do is an npm install in the directory that your projects `package.json` file is located in. That will installed the specific versions your project requires locally. Be aware when you do run your project with say an `ng serve` or `ng build` you will likely get a warning message - something like " your global version is greater than your local version - Angular is using your local version - to prevent getting this message in the future do the following etc..."

If you don't want to disable the message you can always uninstall your Global version (`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`)and reninstall targeting the version your project uses. For example if you project is using Angular version4 you can do `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.3`

**Note: I suggest you double check your `package.json` to verify which versions you're using before installing

Comment: Just to add to this answer for the OP ... note that Angular and the Angular CLI are two *different* things. You may have installed the Angular CLI globally, but most of the time Angular is installed local to a particular project as stated above.

Answer (score -1):

I was having issues with one of my projects that was built using angular 8.0.3 but i stupidly updated angular to angular 9 .
Tried everything installing older versions of the cli etc.

simply ran 'yarn' and it installed the correct version that the project was made using.

I love yarn.

Comment: You tell a story what you encountered and did and what you love. It is not clear how this is related to the question. Please extend your response with an answer to the question.